# Convergence in measure problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f_n=\sqrt{x^4+\frac{x}{n}}$ and $f(x)=x^2$ be functions on $(0,\infty)$. Prove that $f_n \to f$ in measure on $(0,\infty)$ and $f_n^2 \nrightarrow  f^2$ in measure on $(0,\infty)$.

Here the set is infinity, so converge a.e. does not imply converge in measure. Then how to prove that $f_n \to f$ in measure on $(0,\infty)$? I tried to prove by definition, but I don't know how to proceed.

Could someone kindly give some hints or answer? Thanks!